# How to get the refreshed database on the same page before starting with the comparison?

Tags: php, javascript

I am saving/updating data through a page and on the same submit, I need to compare the updated data with some other data. But it compares the new data only after the page is refreshed once. If not, it compares with the old data. How to get the refreshed database on the same page before starting with the comparison ??

Comment: [Any code you can show us?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

After submit your form, you can refer to `field1` with `$_REQUEST['field1']` , `field2` with `$_REQUEST['field2']` and so on.